# Using windows ftp command to login with ssh key

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, ftp

I have google but found that what I want to do is possible using a third-party software, but can anyone answer this question:

I'm trying to ftp to linux server running sftp. I'm tryinh to connect to it automatically using a batch script. I have accomplish this using the command:

```
ftp -i -s:"Path to a text file containing FTP commands"
```

This works find however now I need to use a ssh key to authenticate is this possible using this method and no third-party software?

This is a sample of the text file being passed to the ftp command:

```
open "IP of server"
username
password
mget *
bye
```

Comment: just want to make sure you understand the difference between ftp and sftp.  sftp is secure.  ftp is not.  ALL data will be transferred in plaintext, which defeats the purpose of sftp

Comment: Do you mean FTP or sftp? Which version/vendor at each end? It's all about where you put your public key on the Linux server, and what format it needs. So it depends on what you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this very excellent tutorial on how to set up ssh keys so you do not have to use a password: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html.  That will give you background on the process.

**This assumes both client and server are running some flavor of unix (OSX included)!**

If they are not (in your case), or if you have a non-standard configuration, then there is a pretty high probability that you will need to use third party software to hold the keys.

Once that is set up, you should use `sftp` instead of `ftp`.

Comment: @Russekk Uhl thank for the explination of the diference between sftp and ftp. I have completed the project. The route I choosed was to use a key indeed, however this is an schedule task project so I wanted the key enter manually. The work around I choose was to use WinSCP with their program pageant being the key manager this required the passphrase for a key to be entered once and no need to enter again after that. I shall close this thread thanks